# How to print all text until it sees ';' by awk?

Tags: awk

Can you help me to parse this text by awk?
As you can see in the result, only first line of SQL statement is displayed but I want to print all SQL statement until it ends with ';'.
I think I should make a loop for that but I am not sure how I should do.

For some reasons, below awk code should be kept(first 4 lines of code).

```
/\] / {

getline;
getline;

if ( index($0,"update ") ) {
```

## Data

```
-- [1] Thu Nov 21 21:59:10 2013

update owner.table_name t 
set col1 = '2222',
col2='111111',
col3='111111',
col4='111111',
col5='111111',
col6='111111';

-- [1] Sat Nov 23 21:11:19 2015

update owner2.table_name2 t 
set col1 = '2222',
col2='111111',
col6='111111';
```

## AWK

```
/\] / {

getline;
getline;

if ( index($0,"update ") ) {

splitHipen=$2;
split(splitHipen,splitHipenArr,".");

TABLE_OWNER=splitHipenArr[1];
TABLE_NAME=splitHipenArr[2];
DML=$1;

if(u||index($0,"update ")) { u=1; SQL_STATEMENT=$0; }
if(index($0,";") && u) {u=0;print ""}

printf "%s#%s#%s#%s#\n", TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,DML,SQL_STATEMENT;             

}

}
```

## Current result

```
owner#table_name#update#update owner.table_name t #
owner2#table_name2#update#update owner2.table_name2 t #
```

## Desired output

```
owner#table_name#update#update owner.table_name t set col1 = '2222', col2='111111', col3='111111', col4='111111', col5='111111', col6='111111' #
owner2#table_name2#update#update owner2.table_name2 t set col1 = '2222', col2='111111', col6='111111' #
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace**

```
if(index($0,";") && u) {u=0;print ""}
```

**to**

```
while(getline > 0){SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT " "$0;if(index($0,";")) break}
```

Output

```
owner#table_name#update#update owner.table_name t  set col1 = '2222', col2='111111', col3='111111', col4='111111', col5='111111', col6='111111';#
owner2#table_name2#update#update owner2.table_name2 t  set col1 = '2222', col2='111111', col6='111111';#
```

Comment: You saved my time huge. It is well adaptable into my current code, and it works well.!!! [while...break] is the thing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
/^update/,/;$/ {     # between "update" and ";" do
  if($0~/^update/) { # if it starts with update, get the owner#table_name
    foo=$2"#";       # end with "#"
    gsub(/\./,"#",foo) 
  } foo=foo""substr($0,1,length($0))" " # build the output variable
} 
/;$/ {  # print the variable ofter ; 
  print foo
}
' test3.in
```

Comment: Thanks James. Can you let me know how I can put the code in my previous code block?

Comment: I am surprised with very kind and wonderful people in this community all the time. Cool.